# which branch of maths studies Standard Logical Matrices

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question, advice, nonclassical-logic

In classical logic you have truthtables like:

```
 & | T | F  
---|---|---  
 T | T | F  
 F | F | F
```

In many valued logic you have tables like:

(this one is of four valued Łukasiewicz logic)

```
 Cpq q= | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 || Np || Designated  
--------|---|---|---|---||----||-----    
 p = 0  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 || 3  ||  no  
 p = 1  | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 || 2  ||  no  
 p = 2  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 || 1  ||  yes  
 p = 3  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 || 0  ||  yes
```

Gottwald in ( http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/ )
calls them "Standard Logical Matrices", and I also have seen names like Cayley matrices, and many valued truthtables.
But i was wondering is there an other name for them and which branch of mathematics does study them in depth?

In short the only criteria for these tables are:

1. a set $S$ of values (four in this case)
2. a (proper) subset of $S$ called the designated values
3. an (unrestricted) number of functions:

   $S \to S$
   $S \times S \to  S$
   and maybe even $S^n \to S$

That are all fundamental criteria,

(for Standard Logical Matrices there is an extra  truthp reservation criteria but can be overlooked here)

I had a look into abstract algebra / universal algebra/ algebraic structures but all these fields  seems only to look into systems where the matrices have to submit to some strict criteria, or only allow a very limited amount of functions.

Is there a branch of mathematics that studies these matrices in a more general way? (and what is a good introduction to this branch?)

in many valued logic you study only one (set of) Standard Logical Matrices at a time, but i am wondering is there a branch of mathematics that study them in a more general way?

Comment: You can get certain particularly important kinds of generalized truth tables from Heyting algebras. These are related to intuitionistic logic, pointless topology, and topos theory. This part of mathematics is a mix of logic, topology, and category theory. Another keyword here is "subobject classifier."

Comment: Anyway, keep in mind that if you don't require anything then you probably can't prove anything. A set $S$ equipped with a binary operation $S \times S \to S$ satisfying no other requirements is called a magma ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra) ), for example, but there is really not much to say about these.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan There exists 16 magmas of order 2.  Up to isomorphism, there exist 10 magmas of 2 elements.  Conjecture: The family of magmas **M** of a given finite order has more elements than **M** up to isomorphism.  Conjecture: For any monomorphism M from a magma A-1 of a finite order n to a magma A-2 of order (n+k), where (n+k)>n, there exists a finite number of magmas of order (n+k) M is also a map from A-1.  We can in principle say much more.

Comment: There's a volume called "Theory of Logical Calculi: Basic Theory of Consequence Operations" by Ryszard Wojcicki.  It has a 50+ page chapter on "Logical Matrices".  I think it reaches the level of generality that you seek, but I can't quite tell, in part because I haven't read the entire book and what I've scanned/ quarter-read, I'm not sure I've understood to a meaningful extent.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood (Generalized) Logical Matrices are studied in a field called **Abstract Algebraic Logic**. The author of the question might want to check [this survey](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1024621922509) by Font, Jansana and Pigozzi.

Comment: @JMarcos I found this paper http://www.uni-log.org/Survey50.pdf and the term "abstract algebraic logic" provided what looks like a useful google search (though the Wikipedia warns me that some people use that term to mean something else).  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mien, the best bet you can do is searching through the handbooks of Dov Gabbay, there are 13 volumes, you bound to find something on your topic.